# Email multiple pictures in one email

Tags: email, images

When I take a picture with my android phone I can view it then goto "Share" and it will give me the option to email it to someone through gmail but it will only let me send 1 picture at a time. Is there a way to send multiple picture attachments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Gmail app, simply start a new message, then choose `Menu | Attach` and select what you want to attach. You'll need to repeat for each file, but you can certainly add more than one.